# Express: Image from vue.js is not redirected to backend

Tags: javascript, vue.js, express, file, express-fileupload

I have a vue app which calls the backend through express. When I add an image to a request the request is not redirected to the backend. However, when I call the backend directly from the vue app, without express, the request is handeled correctly. The image gets lost somehow on the way.

Vue-code:

```
    uploadImage(){
        this.loadingImage = true
        const url = "/person/"+localStorage.getItem("userUuid")+"/picture";
        var config = {headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer "+localStorage.getItem("token")}};
        const fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('image', this.picture, this.picture.name)
        this.$http.post(url, fd, config)
        .then((response) => {
             console.log(response)
            this.loadingImage = false
             //window.location.reload()
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
```

app.js

```
const proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
const express = require('express')
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const app = express();

app.post('/person/:id/picture', proxy(config.backendURL, {
    filter: function(req, res) {return checkBearer(req, res)}
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently what you are attempting to do is locate the images in the public folder, as browsers assume that `/<path>` using the same host and port. In your case, you are using express so your API/Webserver is on a different host and or port. With your current configuration, you would have to have your images hosted in the `/public` directory in vue for it to work as expected.

Therefore you need to tell your browser to look elsewhere for the image. Since it is on the same domain (`localhost`) and is on a different port you can use a computed property to return the current hostname. Assuming you are on your local machine it would be `localhost` or we can get the domain dynamically through [`window.location.hostname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/hostname).

In Vue add a computed property to get your domain/hostname and change the port number like so:

```js
computed:{
   baseUri(){
        return `${window.location.hostname}:3000`;
   }
}
```

Then modify your URL to include the hostname we got from our computed property

```js
const url = `${this.baseUri}/person/${localStorage.getItem("userUuid")}/picture`;
```

Now your images should load from the correct server

---

You can also add some logic to your computed property, let's say your image URLs are hosted on a different domain in production, but when you are developing locally they are running from express on your local server.

```
computed:{
   baseUri(){
        return process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 
            `${window.location.hostname}:3000`:
            'myimages.mydomain.com'; // <-- you can also change the port here if you need
   }
}
```